# How to fix this "Input past end of file" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I get an "Input past end of file" error with the code below after the step "readall = myfile.readall":

VBA Code:

```
Sub Paste_Pivot()
Sheets("Missing").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim newwb As Workbook
Set newwb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject, readall As Variant
Dim myfile As Scripting.TextStream
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim fileName As String
fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Desktop.htm"
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    fileName:=fileName, Sheet:=newwb.Sheets(1).Name, Source:=newwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
End With
readall = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1).readall

Dim o As Outlook.Application
Set o = New Outlook.Application
Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set omail = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)

omail.HTMLBody = "Hello" & "<Br>" & "<table align=left>" & readall & "</table"
omail.Display
End Sub
```

Any idea how this can be solved? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you expect from the line `fso.CreateTextFile ("Desktop")`?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try replacing of:

```
fso.CreateTextFile ("Desktop")
newwb.PublishObjects.Add(xlSoureRange, "Desktop", "sheet1", newwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, xlHtmlStatic).Publish (True)
Set myfile = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop")
readall = myfile.readall
```

with:

```
dim fileName As String
fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Desktop.htm"
newwb.Sheets(1).Activate
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _ 
    Filename:=fileName, Sheet:=newwb.Sheets(1).Name, Source:=newwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)      
        .Publish (True) 
        .AutoRepublish = False 
End With
readall = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1).ReadAll
```

It creates a `htm` file named `"Desktop.htm"`, in the path of the workbook keeping the code, then places its content in `readall` variable...

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I now face a runtime error 1004 at the line ".Publish (True)"

Comment: @db2020  Is there a sheet named "sheet1" in the active workbook? It cannot publish because one of the parameters is not appropriate... Instead of `Sheet:="sheet1"`, try using `Sheet:=newwb.Sheets(1).Name`. In fact, I will adapt the answer in this way...

Comment: @db2020 Please, test the updated code. It was a typo (`ThisWorbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`)...

Comment: No, there is no sheet1 in the workbook. I still face the same issue after the adjustment unfortunately. Also made the other adjustments (ThisWorkbook and Desktop.html).

Comment: @db2020 Do you use the updated code? I tested it (now) and works as it should! And if it was not any "Sheet1", how to work using such a sheet name? In the updated version it takes the first sheet name, anyhow... Not 'html'. 'htm'...

Comment: I am now using the (updated) code mentioned in my intial post, is there still something wrong in that code? I keep having the 1004 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247056/discussion-between-db2020-and-faneduru).

Comment: @db2020 Which is the description of the error? Does your user has enough permissions to write in that folder?

Comment: "Method Publish of object PublishObject failed", and yes I have all the necessary rights